# Mongodb-kafka connector failing while connecting MSK to Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector, aws-msk-connect

Im trying to connect MongoDB with AWS Managed kafka using the source connector (downloaded from Confluent Hub), but while creating AWS connector im getting the error message:
`Code: InvalidInput.InvalidConnectorConfiguration  Message: The connector configuration is invalid.Message: Request failed.`

configurations file in connector:

```
name=mongo-source 
connector.class=com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector 
tasks.max=1 
connection.uri=<Connection.uri> 
database=<database.name> 
collection=<coll.name> 
topic.prefix=Topic1
```

mongo-kafka connector: https://www.confluent.io/hub/mongodb/kafka-connect-mongodb

What are the correct configurations for mongo-kafka confluent connecter and is there a way to see the logs for the msk connector to identity which configuration is issue here

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found below configuration works,

```
connector.class=com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector
database=<mongodb database>
tasks.max=1
topics=<your kafka topic>
connection.uri= <mongodb url>
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
collection=<mongodb collection>
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
```

Please make sure to change key and value converters appropriately.
[you can get more support here](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/languages/java/integrating-mongodb-amazon-apache-kafka/)

note: you can use value converter as per your requirement. (string,byte array, json)