# Aws msk kafka sink connector with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

Im creating a sink connector for mongodb using msk connect. The data I'm publishing to kafka topic is protof encoded.

```
connector.class=com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
database=MongoDBMSKDemo
tasks.max=1
topics=MongoDBMSKDemo.Source
connection.uri= <mongodb connection url>
value.converter.schemas.enable=true
collection=Sink
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter
max.batch.size=10
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
```

But the data not getting stored in mongodb getting below error.

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Could not convert value `[B@51798b7f` into a BsonDocument.
```

Can anyone please tell me how to get through this?

Comment: That is because your `value,converter` is `ByteArrayConverter`

Comment: Can you help me to correct it?

Comment: [Your answer here says StringConverter works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76482286/2308683), so why use ByteArrayConverter? But for Protobuf, have you tried ProtobufConverter instead? Can you share how you're serializing the data? Are you using Schema Registry?

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes it worked for string converters, but the thing is data in my kafka topic is protobuf encoded, do apache have protobuf converter ? if so where I can put my protobuf defs?

Comment: Apache doesn't, but Confluent and BlueApron do have Protobuf converters you can find on the web. Again, are you using Schema Registry, or not?

Comment: Here's an example using Protobuf with AWS glue and msk https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/introducing-protocol-buffers-protobuf-schema-support-in-amazon-glue-schema-registry/

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes I created a msk registry in msk glue, but in sink conector what should be the `value.converter` ? is it `io.confluent.connect.protobuf.ProtobufConverter` as im in aws context would it work?

Comment: It will work if you install that library and run Confluent Schema Registry on your own, otherwise, AWS Glue has a different package name for their converters https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-schema-registry/blob/master/protobuf-kafkaconnect-converter/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/schemaregistry/kafkaconnect/protobuf/ProtobufSchemaConverter.java

Comment: @OneCricketeer tried with above case and I getting  ```There is an issue with the connector
Code: InvalidInput.InvalidConnectorConfiguration
Message: The connector configuration is invalid. Message: Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 1 error(s): Invalid value com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.kafkaconnect.protobuf.ProtobufSchemaConverter for configuration value.converter: Class com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.kafkaconnect.protobuf.ProtobufSchemaConverter could not be found.```

Comment: my sink connector configuration is  ```
connector.class=com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector
value.converter=com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.kafkaconnect.protobuf.ProtobufSchemaConverter
value.converter.schemas.enable=true
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter.registry.name=p8-proto-defs
value.converter.schemaName=ExecutionReport.proto
value.converter.endpoint=https://glue.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
value.converter.region=us-east-2
value.converter.schemaAutoRegistrationEnabled=true
value.converter.dataFormat=PROTOBUF
```

Comment: `Class ... could not be found` means you're missing a JAR file. It's not a config issue